# How can I configure auto-dim-other-buffers to dim line number column?

Tags: emacs

I am using `auto-dim-other-buffers-mode`, but unfortunately this mode does not change the color of the line number column.

I am using `line-number-mode` for displaying relative line numbers.

I have tried to customize `auto-dim-other-buffers face` but have had no success.

I also have tried editing `line-number face` which allows me to change the color of the column that I wish for auto-dim to take care of.

What options do I have here?